# Accepting relative paths in JSoup clean for <img> tags

Tags: jsoup

The following is an example of the text I need to parse.

```
<P>The symbol <IMG id="pic1" height=15 src="images/itemx/image001.gif" width=18>indicates......</P>
```

I need to perform a cleanup. So applying the following code will remove the src attribute as it doesn't start with a valid protocol. Anyway to configure Jsoup to pickup the attribute? I want to avoid using absolute url if possible.

```
Jsoup.clean(content, Whitelist.basicWithImages());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The jsoup cleaner will allow relative links, as long as a `base URI` is specified when cleaning. This is so the link's protocol can be confirmed against the allowed protocols. Note that in your example, you're using the clean method without a base URI, so the link cannot be resolved and so must be removed.

E.g.:

```java
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, "http://example.com/", 
   Whitelist.basicWithImages());
```

Note that in the current version, any relative links will be converted to absolute links after cleaning. I've just [committed a change](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/7171cec2dfd3c8b58645b69970425864abf8ba1f) (available in the next release) which will optionally allow relative links to be preserved.

Syntax will be:

```java
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, "http://example.com/",
    Whitelist.basicWithImages().preserveRelativeLinks(true));
```

Comment: Thanks. Your change to preserve relative links will be a perfect solution for my situation.

Comment: I'm not sure which release it is being referred to, but at the time of writing the newest version is 1.7.2 and it has the option to preserve relative links.

Comment: See also [How does URL detection work in Jsoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142187/jsoup-parse-vs-jsoup-parse-or-how-does-url-detection-work-in-jsoup)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer does not work for me, because I have to support multiple domains (including multiple dev environment and multiple production sites). So we really need the relative URLs (regardless of the dangers that it brings). So here's what I did to do it:

```
// allow relative URLs. JSoup doesn't support that, so we use reflection
// removing the list of allowed protocols, which means all protocols are allowed
Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(WHITELIST.getClass(), "protocols");
ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
ReflectionUtils.setField(field, WHITELIST, Maps.newHashMap());
```

(`ReflectionUtils` is a class by spring, which simply wraps the checked exceptions thrown by the reflection API)

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful:

```
whitelist.removeProtocols("a", "href", "ftp", "http", "https", "mailto");
whitelist.removeProtocols("img", "src", "http", "https");
```

Comment: Whatever the side effects may be: this results in the code I expected!