# Jsoup.parse() vs. Jsoup.parse() - or How does URL detection work in Jsoup?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Jsoup has 2 *html* parse() methods:

1. [parse(String html)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) - "As no base URI is specified, absolute URL
   detection relies on the HTML including a  tag."
2. [parse(String html, String baseUri)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) - "The URL where the HTML
   was retrieved from. Used to resolve relative URLs to absolute URLs,
   that occur before the HTML declares a  tag."

I am having a difficulty understanding the *meaning* of the difference between the two:

1. In the 2nd `parse()` version, what does "resolve relative URLs to absolute URLs, that occur
   **before** the HTML declares a `<base href>` tag" mean? What if a
   `<base href>` tag *never* occurs in the page?
2. What is the purpose of absolute URL detection? Why does Jsoup need
   to find the absolute URL?
3. Lastly, but most importantly: Is `baseUri` the full URL of HTML page
   (as phrased in original documentation) or is it the **base** URL of
   the HTML page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used for among others [`Element#absUrl()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl%28java.lang.String%29) so that you can retrieve the (intended) absolute URL of an `<a href>`, `<img src>`, `<link href>`, `<script src>`, etc. E.g.

```java
for (Element link : document.select("a")) {
    System.out.println(link.absUrl("href"));
}
```

This is very useful if you want to download and/or parse the linked resources as well.

---

> *In the 2nd parse() version, what does "resolve relative URLs to absolute URLs, that occur before the HTML declares a `<base href>` tag" mean? What if a `<base href>` tag never occurs in the page?*

Some (poor) websites may have declared a `<link>` or `<script>` with a relative URL *before* the `<base>` tag. Or if there is no means of a `<base>` tag, then just the given `baseUri` will be used for resolving relative URLs of the entire document.

---

> *What is the purpose of absolute URL detection? Why does Jsoup need to find the absolute URL?*

In order to return the right URL on `Element#absUrl()`. This is purely for enduser's convenience. Jsoup doesn't need it in order to successfully parse the HTML at its own.

---

> *Lastly, but most importantly: Is baseUri the full URL of HTML page (as phrased in original documentation) or is it the base URL of the HTML page?*

The former. If the latter, then documentation would be lying. The `baseUri` must not to be confused with `<base href>`.

Comment: This is a fantastically helpful answer (as always). A few clarifications: (1) Is Jsoup capable of deriving `<base href>`? If so, since it isn't `TreeBuilder.getBaseUri()`, what is the method that returns the value of `<base href>`? (2) Where, in [Jsoup's source code](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/parser/TreeBuilder.java), can I find how the "magic" of deriving the `baseUri` from HTML only being done?

Comment: It's set in [`TreeBuilderState` line 97](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/parser/TreeBuilderState.java#L97) and it's available by `Node#getBaseUri()` of all nodes which are created after `<base>`.

Comment: You probably meant `Node#baseUri()`. Now to what really confuses me: When calling `parse()` baseUri means **full* URL path. But when calling `Node#baseUri()` it only means `<base>` URL... See the asymmetry? Also `Node#baseUri()` is not guaranteed to be initialized properly, so what does it return then? Lastly, can a valid baseUri be derived from an HTML page, even when no `<base>` exists there? +1,000,000

Comment: If the `baseUri` is set during `parse()`, it will be used as base URL. Once Jsoup discovers a `<base>`, it will be used instead. If the `baseUri` is not set during `parse()`, it remains empty until there's a `<base>`. There's really no other way to know the original URL a HTML file was requested with other than just using `connect()` on an URL directly instead of `parse()` on a string. The HTML document does not contain that information.

Comment: It just occurred to me the `parse()` version **without** the baseUri parameter is **much better** than the other `parse()` version because it allows me to check whether the value returned by `Node#baseUri()` could be used as a base URI. Does that make any sense? i.e. if it's empty, we at least know that there was no `<base>` in the page and try to accommodate that somehow. If we use the other `parse()` method, then we can't really tell whether the value returned by `Node#baseUri()` is the (full) page URL passed or the one discovered by Jsoup. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's relevant as you'd usually like to use `Node#absUrl()` to get the final absolute URL of the URL attribute for further parsing, without worrying about `Node#baseUri()` yourself.

Comment: Are you implying that `Node#absUrl()` **always** returns the correct absolute URL for **any** relative link on any given page, even when the page doesn't contain a `<base>`?

Comment: No, I am not. It will only do that when `baseUri` is specified during `parse()`, for the case that the document doesn't contain a `<base>`.