# Whats the difference between jsoup.connect and jsoup.parse?

Tags: android, jsoup

What is the differece between `jsoup.connect` and `jsoup.parse`? It seems like both do the same work `Jsoup.connect(URL);` and `Jsoup.parse(Html);`.

Answer (score 1):

As you just wrote in your question, `connect()` takes a **URL**.
It then sends an HTTP request and parses the result.

`parse()` takes a string of raw HTML, and does not involve a network.

Comment: @GunjitDhawan - This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142187/jsoup-parse-vs-jsoup-parse-or-how-does-url-detection-work-in-jsoup